# Gizmo3D SLA + Monocure resins not curing

Tags: print-quality, sla, dlp, resin

I am working with a "Gizmo3D" type DLP resin printer, and using Monocure "General Grey" resin.  I'm having some issues with getting this resin to cure to the build plate well enough to prevent it from "wandering" across during the print, without "cooking" the resin and distorting it.

Does anyone have experience using this family of resin that could suggest some of their process details?  I am getting acceptable quality incremental print with 100 micron (0.1 mm) layer thickness and a resin temp of 25 °C but I am having issues with the layers of the model "peeling away" from the base layers that get put down on the build plate first.

Comment: Welcome to 3dPrinting.SE!

Answer (score 1):

I get best results from sun curing by putting it in water in the sun for 20-30 min.

I personally do not like Monocure Red one. I find the Nova3D prints better, has a lower oder, and cheaper.